# Factorize an integer into two integers in R

Tags: r

I want to factorize any integer into two integers and save the result in R. For example, `28` should be saved as `1 X 28, 28 X 1, 2 X 14, 14 X 2, 4 X 7, 7 X 4`.

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
 v1 <- 28
 x1 <- seq_len(v1)
 v2 <- combn(x1[v1%%x1==0], 2)
 v3 <- v2[,apply(v2, 2, FUN = prod) ==28]
 apply(cbind(v3, apply(v3, 2, rev)), 2, paste, collapse="*")
 #[1] "1*28" "2*14" "4*7"  "28*1" "14*2" "7*4"
```